# How to update fire app builder leanback library?

Tags: android, android-tv, television, leanback

`Fireapp builder` uses older version of lean back i.e `com.android.support:leanback-v17:`**`23.1.1`**. I need to make the customized design that needs leanback updated library i.e  `com.android.support:leanback-v17:`**`28.0.0`** because this library has the classes that I need to use in my code. I need to know how do I update the library.

Comment: Based from this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive), the `android.support.v17.leanback` has been deprecated since 2016. Try to use other available library.

Comment: I know jess "com.android.support:leanback-v17:23.1.1"  has been deprecated since 2016. but my question is  how to update fire app builder leanback library ?